# import module in different contexts

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a file structure like this:

```
work/
├─ analysis.ipynb
├─ app/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ class_a.py
│  ├─ script.py
│  ├─ utils.py
```

File `class_a.py` contains a class `MyClass` and also an import from `utils` like this:

```py
from utils import useful_function

class MyClass():
    ...
```

Then I try to import `MyClass` in `analysis.ipynb` like this:

```py
from app.class_a import MyClass
```

and get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8eeb8559d767> in <module>
      2 import os
      3 from datetime import datetime
----> 4 from app.class_a import MyClass
      5 from app.utils import useful_function
      6 ...

~/Documents/work/app/class_a.py in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 from utils import useful_function
      3 
      4 class MyClass():
      5     '''indeed very necessary class for me

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

I have figured out that if I change all imports in `app` folder to something like this:

```py
from app.utils import useful_function
```

Then I can import all I need from `analysis.ipynb`

However `app` should work as something I run with `python script.py` and that does not work unless imports are written in the original way.

I do not understand modules and packaging and so can not even ask a question precisely, but how do I align import "styles" in order to both be able to run `python scripts.py` from the `app` directory and import `MyClass` from `analys.ipynb`?

Comment: The problem is, if you write `app.utils`, python tries to find the `utils` from inside the `app` subfolder, which does not exist in the context of `class_a`.

Comment: @white, intuitively I understood this. I am able to run script.py and analysis.py with some changes in code. What I am looking for is a way to run them both without those changes.

Comment: You could use a wrapper script that manages the imports. Supply it with the script you want to run as parameter like `python wrapper.py app` and read the parameter with `sys.argv[1]`. That way, your context stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` statements search through the list of paths in `sys.path`, so I've added these lines to my `analysis.ipynb`:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/work/app/')
```

In case someone would have the same question and struggle as me.